# How does the Contingency spell with Cure Wounds as the contingent spell work with incoming damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, healing

If a bard selects the *contingency* spell as a Magical Secrets pick, and uses *contingency* to cast a contingent 5th-level *cure wounds* with the trigger "when I drop to 1 hit point", how does the incoming damage work?

Say he is at 5 hit points. Then he gets hit with 30 damage. Does the extra 25 damage take away from the 5th-level *cure wounds* that gets triggered?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: please hold off on accepting answers (even mine) immediately. Someone might come along with a better idea! We often encourage (but not demand) that Questions wait 24 hours to accept an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The extra damage does not count against the heal spell, but you made a mistake on your contingency trigger.

The dnd-5e rules basically state that when you take extra damage over your total, you're reduced to zero hit points and need to start making death saving throws.

> ### Dropping to 0 Hit Points
>
> When you drop to 0 Hit Points, you either die
> outright or fall Unconscious
>
> ### Instant Death
>
> Massive damage can kill you instantly. When damage
> reduces you to 0 Hit Points and there is damage remaining, you die if
> the remaining damage equals or exceeds your hit point maximum.
>
> For example, a Cleric with a maximum of 12 Hit Points currently has 6
> Hit Points. If she takes 18 damage from an Attack, she is reduced to 0
> Hit Points, but 12 damage remains. Because the remaining damage equals
> her hit point maximum, the Cleric dies.
>
> ### Falling Unconscious
>
> If damage reduces you to 0 Hit Points and fails to
> kill you, you fall Unconscious (see Conditions ). This unconsciousness
> ends if you regain any Hit Points.

So the order of things would be:

1. Take more damage than your total hit points
2. Get reduced to zero hit points (and go unconscious, lose concentration, etc.)
3. Assuming instant death doesn't occur, contingency kicks in* and heals you for **X** hit points, making your hit point total **X**
4. Profit.

*BTW: Your contingency should state *"When I get reduced to 1 **or fewer** hit points."*

As originally stated you'd have to hit exactly 1 HP for it to trigger, allowing you to blow right past 1 to 0 when you take more damage.

Comment: The text reads: `she is reduced to 0 Hit Points, but 12 damage remains.` so even if you get healed by *X* amount, you'd have *X-12* HP now because you need to heal the remaining damage.

Comment: @JohnHamilton that's only for Instant Death calculation purposes. There are no negative hit points in 5e

Comment: @STTLCU What I meant is, this looks like it could also prevent Instant Death clause because the contingency would kick in before the death but your new hit points would become *X-12* instead of your immediate death. Or at least that's how it sounds to me.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I'm not sure, it doesn't sound right to me

Comment: That's what Death Ward is for. "The first time the target would drop to 0 Hit Points as a result of taking damage, the target instead drops to 1 hit point, and the spell ends."

Comment: @john no. This contigency trigger is based on the HP total. The damage is **applied**, the three considerations in the quoted text are evaluated and then the damaging event ends. Only then the contigency trigger happens, the 12 extra damage foregone as there's no negative HP total. Compare that to the **Death Ward** spell. Its wording states that the trigger for that spell happens before the damage is **applied**. Death Ward ignores the damage dealt and then sets the HP to 1. And to OP's bard, using DW would be cheaper than the contigency cure wounds.

Comment: @Mindwin That means in the Cleric example the Cleric would just outright die. Still not convinced but it's a different view so I accept it. In my case though I'd rule the Cleric not dead and apply the lingering damage to the healing.

Comment: @john if you are the DM, you rule as you will, so long your table are having fun everything is just fine. But this is stackexchange and we need to stick to the rules. As I said in several other places, 5e to me seems much like MtG in their effect resolution.

Comment: RAW seems to indicate that the taking of damage is essentially an atomic action or "it takes place instantaneously" - So the damage, the reduction of HP to 0 and the instant death calculation all happen before the contingency can trigger.

Answer (score 7):

### Damage occurs all at once, thus, very technically, your *contingency* will not activate

The rules on "[Damage and Healing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageandHealing)" state:

> [...] Whenever a creature takes damage, that damage is subtracted from its hit points [...]

It doesn't state that the damage is dealt 1 hit point at a time, it is all at once. This means that you will immediately drop to 0 hit points (as 5e doesn't have negative hit points). This technically means that *contingency* won't activate because you never dropped to 1 hit point, you dropped to 0.

Another thing worth remembering is that [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) always activates *after* its trigger:

> [...] The contingent spell takes effect immediately after the circumstance is met for the first time, whether or not you want it to, and then contingency ends [...]

### Even if you have it trigger when you reach 0 hit points, you will still briefly fall unconscious

This is true because *contingency* occurs after its trigger, and thus you would have reached 0 hit points and as the section on "[Dropping to 0 Hit Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Droppingto0HitPoints)" explains:

> When you drop to 0 hit points, you either die outright or fall unconscious [...]

Ultimately this means that you, for an instant, will fall [unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Unconscious) (assuming you don't instantly die from excessive damage) and thus:

> The creature drops whatever it's holding and falls prone.

---

Compare this set-up to the [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) spell which states:

> [...] The first time the target **would drop to 0 hit points** as a result of taking damage, the target **instead drops to 1 hit point**, and the spell ends [...]

The *death ward* spell will instead cause the creature to take all 30 of the damage, and then end up at 1 hit point, never falling unconscious.

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down into steps. This answer is really helpful!

Comment: Couldn't you define a matching trigger for contingency ? As in match the exact death ward wording ?

Comment: @eagle Except *contingency* would occur after that trigger so you would actually reach 0 hit points. *death ward* makes a very specific exception with its timing that you can't replicate with *contingency*

Answer (score 5):

## Contingency occurs after the event defined.

> The contingent spell takes effect immediately after the circumstance is met for the first time, whether or not you want it to, and then contingency ends.

This means that the damage has to occur. There's no way to "stop" in between the damage numbers, so to speak.

If you actually meant "when I drop to 1 hit point", then Contingency wouldn't actually be triggered, because the character went from 5 HP straight to 0 HP.

Assuming you meant "When my character has 1 or fewer hit points":

So, in this case, the bard would take the 30 damage and go to 0 hp. Now, Contingency kicks in. Assuming that they aren't dead for some reason, then they would gain the benefit of Cure Wounds and be at positive hit points.

---

**A Note about 0 HP** : Remember, that a creature that has 0 HP is unconscious (barring a some of exceptions(s?) - Zealot Barbarians), even if it's only for an instant. This directly affects concentration, some poisons, etc.